# Sequelize: instance.get is not a function (after upgrade)

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

On Sequelize version 3.x.x, the application runs perfectly with no issues. I tried to update this to version 4.x.x and fixed all the compile issues. However, there are some occasions where a sequelize error is thrown such as `instance.getGroup is not a function`. However, the IDE does allow me to pre-populate the methods on the instance, but upon auto complete it fills it to `instance.getGroup`

I have included some code below that I think is useful for the situation.

```
export interface IAccountInstance extends Sequelize.Instance<IAccountAttributes>, IAccountAttributes {
     /**
      * Gets all the Team objects associated with this instance.
      */
     getGroup: Sequelize.BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin<IGroupInstance>;
}
```

How the getGroups is invoked: When GraphQL requests an attribute of `groups` that exist on the `account` object, it will resolve with `instance.getGroup()` (this is where it breaks on v4, and numerous other methods that are done like this)

```
groups: {
            type: new GraphQL.GraphQLList(SchemaRegistrar.schemaMap.groups.graphqlSchema),
            resolve: (instance: IAccountInstance, args: any, context: any): any => {
                   if (!instance) {
                         return null;
                   }
                   return instance.getGroup();
            }
 },
```

From https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v4/docs/upgrade-to-v4.md, I know there are breaking changes but i am having much luck.

How the schemas get initialized, on server startup, an action is called that created all the tables and sequelize models. There is more code but this is generally how it is done

```
const schemaModel: Sequelize.Model<any, any> = ServerGlobals.sequelize.define(
        schemaDef.tableName, schemaDef.sequelizeSchema, {
            instanceMethods: {
                schemaName: schemaDef.schemaName
            },
            freezeTableName: true
        });
```

Sequelize mentions this has changed (which is what needs to be updated in my code?...)

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
...
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (model) {...}
    },
    instanceMethods: {
        someMethod: function () { ...}
    }
});
```

to

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
...
});

// Class Method
Model.associate = function (models) {
    ...associate the models
};

// Instance Method
Model.prototype.someMethod = function () {..}
```

But Model.associate does not work for me and i'm not sure how I would make it work with my setup...

Any help is appreciated. I have gone through other people that have faced this issue but was not able to resolve it based off of their solutions.

**UPDATE 1**
The exact error from the stack trace is `error: instance.getGroup is not a function TypeError: instance.getGroup is not a function`

This is how the relationships are established. After the table schemas are initialized, the following is executed

```
_.forEach(
        this._sortedSchemas, (schema: AbstractSchemaDefinition<any, any>) =>
            schema.createSequelizeRelationships(SchemaRegistrar.schemaMap)
    );
```

`createSequelizeRelationships` is a function that returns nothing, but has the relationship properties to another table such as:

```
schemaMap.accounts.sequelizeModel.hasMany(
    schemaMap.groups.sequelizeModel,
    {
        as: groups,
        foreignKey: accountId
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

So this would be the typical setup for a simple object in a new sequelize project i have... and it took me a while to get the associations to work

This would be in a file called loc_countries.js, and it's imported in the code in the second snippet

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Country = sequelize.define('loc_countries', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    abbr2: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    abbr3: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'loc_countries',
  });

  Country.associate = function (models) {
    models.Country.hasMany(models.ProvinceState, { as: 'ProvStates', foreignKey: 'loc_countries_id' });
  };

  return Country;
};
```

Then in my index.js is where i ran the associations through the forEach you described..

```
const models = {
  Country: sequelize.import('./loc_countries'),
  ProvinceState: sequelize.import('./loc_state_prov'),
  City: sequelize.import('./loc_inc_places'),  
};

Object.keys(models).forEach((modelName) => {
  if ('associate' in models[modelName]) {
    // console.log(models[modelName]);
    models[modelName].associate(models);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Greg. I'll see if I can modify what i have into something you have created...it's just a bit tough on my end as it's an established system (contains ALOT of Schema files I would have to change to have your format). What we have is very similar to https://vivacitylabs.com/setup-typescript-sequelize/ actually. I will keep you posted on what happens